# validating textboxes prior to submission

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button that checks that there is text in each `textbox` using `JavaScript`. It will send an alert if they are not all completed and send another if they are. I'm not too sure how to do this and would like some help completing it. The name of the button and three `textboxes` are shown below.

```html
<input id="checkD" type="button" value="Check Completion">

<input name="nameD" type="text" /><br>
<input name="emailD" type="text" /><br>
<input name="phoneD" type="text" /><br>
```

Comment: Come on kyle, you have to at least try something on your own.  If you did, then post it.  Otherwise do a little googling and see if you can make some progress on your own first.  We aren't here to write code for you.

Comment: Come on Kyle...

Comment: @Toby Yea, what he said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onclick event on button and validate all textbox values

```
<input id="checkD" type="button" onclick="validateTextbox();" value="Check Completion">
```

Please see below fiddle for reference

https://jsfiddle.net/ganesh2412/3ck6a09z/

Answer (score 0):

one approach to accomplishing your task is by using `document.querySelectorAll` to select all the `input` elements of type `text` then simply loop through to check if each individual element has a length greater than `0` then simply display a message according to the outcome.

```js
function validate(){
     var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#testing input[type=text]");
     var flag = true;
     for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){
         if (inputElements[i].value.length == 0){
            alert("please fill all fields");
            flag = false;
            break;
         }
     }

     if(flag) alert("proceed...");
}
```

```html
<form id ="testing" action="/action_page.php">
    <input id="checkD" type="button" value="Check Completion" onclick="validate();">
    <input name="nameD" type="text" /><br>
    <input name="emailD" type="text" /><br>
    <input name="phoneD" type="text" /><br>
</form>
```